# Symfony2 Error Logging

Tags: symfony, logging

I'd like to know how to configure my production environnement to log all the errors. Indeed, I have errors like PHP fatal errors which occured and wasn't logged and I don't understand why. Actually they were log int the apache logs, but is there a way to log all of them in the log folder of my application?

Thanks,
Valentin

Comment: If an error can't be catched (not all php errors can be catched), there is no wy to log them with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several errors that cannot be handled (and thus logged) by your own (or Symfony's/Monolog's) error handlers, cf. the [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) documentation. So while it's possible to log some errors, you can't log all (parse/compile errors, for example). This is a limitation inherent in PHP.

Apparently, there's a workaround by detecting and logging errors in [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php), but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for. :)